# Assignments and Usage of global Variables in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I've got the following problem:

I do understand that the concept of functional programming languages do not allow immutable variables, so classic variable assignment and usage like

```
var foo = bar();

after that in another function...

var baz = funnything(foo);
```

is not possible (correct me if it is, I'm still trying to get the whole idea and concepts behind functional programming).

I'm trying to play around a bit with Clojure and come to a point where I stuck:

I want to get a webpage and save the DOM into a variable for later usage. 
The program starts, a prompt is spawning and the user can enter a URL which he want to fetch.

After the DOM of the website is fetched he can navigate through the DOM by for example getting the title, or all links or whatever.

**The Problem**:
Because I can't use a construct like

```
; More or less pseudo-code
(def page nil)

(get-url [url]
  (page (browser/get url)))

(get-title
    (println (html/select page [:title])))
```

I have to use the following construct:

```
(get-title [url]
    (println (html/select (browser/get url) [:title])))
```

Due to this construct everytime I want to access an element of the site via `get-title`, `get-links` or whatever I have to download the whole webpage whenever the user is entering one of those methods on the command prompt.

Do I miss something here? Are there classical assigments in Clojure? Am I doing the complete thing wrong and should study a whole lot more functional programming concepts before getting hands-on and learning-by-doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misunderstanding assignment in clojure.

```
(page (browser/get url))
```

is not equivalent to: page = browser/get(url), it is equivalent to page(browser/get(url)).

I think you don't really need a global variable, just composable functions. Your example could look something like this:

```
(defn get-title [url]
  (let [page (browser/get url)]
    (println (html/select page [:title]))))
```

That and using memoize, like Joost mentioned, if you want to cache the return values of broser/get.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily cache the value of (browser/get url) so you don't have to refetch the page every time you want to examine a property of it. See `clojure.core/memoize`. But that will only solve part of the problem.

In your particular case, your program *requires* some sort of global (or session scoped), mutable, concept of "the current page" or at least, "the current url", since that is what you're expecting your user to enter and modify. Clojure provides multiple constructs for managing mutable state.

Since you're only dealing with one page at a time, this is probably best modeled by using atoms. See http://clojure.org/atoms and http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/swap!

Comment: Great, atoms were exactly that what I was looking for, Thanks!